# How to write year in full always with same author cited multiple times

Tags: biblatex

I am using the following style:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true
]{biblatex}
```

I have the following two exemplary entries in my bib file

```
@article{HN2018a,
author = {THOMPSON, RAY},
title = {Exemplary Title A},
journal = {The Journal of Bibtex-Examples},
volume = {4343},
number = {2},
pages = {1-2},
year = {2018}
}

@article{HN2018b,
author = {Thompson, RAY},
title = {Exemplary Title B},
journal = {The Journal of Bibtex Second-Entries},
volume = {3},
number = {4},
pages = {1-2},
year = {2018}
}
```

I use this command: `\cite{HN2018a,HN2018b}`

I get:

> Thompson 2018a,b

Two things I do not like about this outcome. First, there is no space after the comma. Second, it would look better imho to have

> Thompson 2018a, 2018b

Is it possible to change this with the used citation style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is hard-coded in `authoryear-comp.cbx` (but it can be customised as `extradateonlycompcitedelim` – what a catchy name – in `biblatex-ext`'s version of the `-comp` styles).

In order to generate these compact citations, `biblatex` needs to remember the year of the last entry. If we can make it forget about that year, we automatically get the desired citation style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, 
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Knuth 1986a, 1986b)]

---

The following solution feels conceptually nicer to me, but requires a *lot* more code. We can redefine the relevant citation bibmacros to remove the test for `\cbx@lastyear` directly.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}%
  \setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
       {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifnameundef{labelname}
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
           \setunit{%
             \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
             \printdelim{nonameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
           \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
             {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
             {}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{%
          \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
          \printdelim{nameyeardelim}\bibopenparen}%
        \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
          {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
          {}%
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}%
     \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
     \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}%
  \setunit{%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
      {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
      {}%
    \textcitedelim}}
\makeatother
```

Compare with the original definitions in [`authoryear-comp.cbx` (ll. 26-114 in v3.14)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/2ddd2836927d08ac600c8fa3af1897417548ac05/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear-comp.cbx#L26-L114).